# Layout for Doc Libs in SP 2013

Tags: document-library, design

I search a layout/design for a more user-frienly presentaion of the document library in Sharepoint 2013.

Who can give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

As my knowledge, no branding template exists with full featured capabilities for document library *(Grouping, Search, Menu...)*

Any way, you can have few directions you can follow according to your requirements:

1. [Display templates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-design-manager-display-templates), you can customize the look and feel of the content search webpart results.
2. [Office CSR](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a) (Client-Side-Rendering), custom JavaScript file for overriding the default rendering template used by the library at different levels *(List Header/Content/Footer, ContentType, Field...)*
3. Old School and **NOT RECOMMENDED**, Xslt Style Sheet, provides XML routines to render Forms *(List View, Edit, New, Item View)*
4. [SPFx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/connect-to-sharepoint) (SharePoint Framework), used only on modern site from SharePoint Online or On-Premise with SharePoint Server 2016 Feature Pack 2